# Change encrypted password on mysql

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, web, passwords

I am trying to enter the admin panel of a web which I don't know the password of, the web has an older backup where I can enter the admin panel, from the old db I copied the field of the old encrypted password that works on the new db, but it does not work, I don't know that much about webs, so I don't really know if the password field is linked to something that decrypts the password, thanks for you help.

[image]

Comment: Most of the time passwords are not encrypted, they are hashed. This mean you cannot unencrypt them, or even unhash them.

Comment: I have access to all the files of the web, is there anything on the files of the site that would help me with that, or it's not realted to the website the hash

Comment: So you have access to the code and database? of both versions of the control panel?

Comment: I have access to the code and database, and I need to enter the admin page of the site

Comment: Can you check to see if the code to register/create the password is the same in both? And check if the field lengths are the same in both databases? Presumably at least one of those is different otherwise copy/paste would work...

Comment: The code is the same, the db fields are the same the only think is the hash code that i'm still trying to find, because all the rest is exactly the same.

Comment: If they were the same then I'd expect it to work. Can you show the code? Or failing that try creating a user on the new system and copy/paste that password...

Comment: what I mean is that from the old web, a new one has been created from that one, changing images and text but it is exactly the same code, thats why it might be the hash code, anyway I'll try that, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the encrypted password, you should know the encrypt algorithm first then you make the another one from plain text password that you know.

Example: you know the algorithm using md5, then u should encrypt text "password" into md5 algorithm then change the password from the db admin, you can encrypt plain text into md5 from this site https://www.md5hashgenerator.com/

Comment: `md5` has been considered `broken` for years - do NOT use it to hash passwords as there are massive hash lookup tables that make finding many passwords trivial. Use `password_hash` within PHP to securely hash the password

Comment: Thanks for your answer, From what you just said the format of the password from the old backup is the same as the new so I guess it's the same format, anyways I will try to find the algorithm of the password and try it another time, thanks!

Comment: Sure things, Good Luck ^^

Answer (score 0):

Probabily will not work. Why?

When you pressing "log/start/sign in,etc", all data form are urlencoded and your password will be transform to hash, or encrypted AND hash.
encryption doesn't matter really (a priori)

If your password is "helloword$1234" it will throw: "a3eb447769293c93f56060b4994a4149" so it means your password will not be "text plain" between client and server for avoid hooks & leaks. Some attackers can get your request with your urencoded data but will not get the real password (encrypted or not) because in throry hash's can not be reversed

Your server will get "a3eb447769293c93f56060b4994a4149" then server-app will get HASHED password from db table (never the real password) to compare between password submited; "a3eb447769293c93f56060b4994a4149" == "a3eb447769293c93f56060b4994a4149".

If you put "a3eb447769293c93f56060b4994a4149" (what you're watching in db table), in login form, that client (front end) will take this "a3eb447769293c93f56060b4994a4149" and will HASH YOUR HASH.
So "a3eb447769293c93f56060b4994a4149" will output "5d88b7458b31365dc9860007dfca5685".-
Then your server-app will get "5d88b7458b31365dc9860007dfca5685" and compare "a3eb447769293c93f56060b4994a4149" == "5d88b7458b31365dc9860007dfca5685" (false). It will reject your because you sent a hash hashed what will never be equal.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, that was really helpful, I now understand why it don't works, about the hash, how I can know the hash of my web and how I can hash a password so I can insert the hashed password on the db, or it's not possible